# Buffer Mat Image from JavaCV

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedimage, javacv, mat

I am reading images from a camera as **Mat** image and I want to buffer them all for fast access.

Say, I want to record `10s 1080p 60hz` video from a camera and buffer all its frame. Each frame needs `6MB` memory space, means that `10 * 60 * 6 = 3600MB`, `3.6GB` for `10s`.

I am looking for some tricks to reduce this size however not losing any speed in computing.